# How to rollback unattended upgrade command

Tags: 18.04, upgrade, uninstall, overheating, software-uninstall

My system hardware is facing abnormal heat after an upgrade. I want to rollback to check if it is the reason for the heat.

I brought the history using:

```
 gedit /var/log/apt/history.log
```

I see a lot of things like:

```
Start-Date: 2020-09-02  12:02:19
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Upgrade: libfreerdp-client2-2:amd64 (2.1.1+dfsg1-0ubuntu0.18.04.1, 2.2.0+dfsg1-0ubuntu0.18.04.1)
End-Date: 2020-09-02  12:02:19
```

How to rollback this upgrade? I do not want to remove the whole package to avoid problems, just remove the upgrade.

Comment: You can roll back an upgrade by specifying the older version (as long as it's still in your local cache): `sudo apt install packagename=version`. However, it's very unlikely that libfreerdp-client2-2 is causing an overheat. Consider checking plain old `top` to see if something is consuming a lot more CPU than usual.

Comment: First, how to know the good old version? Second, I tried top, and found `Web Content` under  the command that is consuing up to 15% of the CPU and `gnome-shell` also consuming up to 27%. Any idea what are those for and how to remove the `gnome-shell`? I am opening the web browser.

Comment: The old version number is clearly listed in the output you provided. Your very limited description of `top` output seems normal for a desktop system with a web browser operating. `gnome-shell` is your desktop -- removal is very unwise. Time to check your hardware: Ensure your fan(s) are running and you don't have dust build-up.