# No more python interpreters in Pycharm after unattended upgrade?

Tags: upgrade, pycharm

I work in Pycharm every day. Yesterday everything seemed fine, although in the evening the Pycharm window wasn't showing in the sidebar on my desktop. This morning as I open Pycharm, it says the python interpreter is not configured for my project. I tried to set it, as usual, but there are not options. I seem to no longer have python interpreters.

I checked my update log and it says the following upgrade happened yesterday:

```
Start-Date: 2021-04-07  08:06:53
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Upgrade: libopenexr22:amd64 (2.2.0-11.1ubuntu1.4, 2.2.0-11.1ubuntu1.6)
End-Date: 2021-04-07  08:06:54
```

I tried to undo it with `sudo apt install libopenexr22=2.2.0-11.1ubuntu1.4` and variations of this, because I'm not sure about the exact command, following this [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1272391/how-to-rollback-unattended-upgrade-command). I got an error every time, because either the package or the version were not found. I also checked the synaptic package manager, but for some reason the history of synaptic doesn't show any updates after February 2020.

I'm not even sure this upgrade caused the problem, but I thought I would try to roll back before reinstalling anaconda. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

I am using Ubuntu 18.04.

[image: A screenshot of the problem]

Comment: Can you indicate which version of Ubuntu are you using?  More importantly, which Python interpreter is missing?  The system-installed one or the one provided by Anaconda?  Your last paragraph about "Anaconda" is somewhat confusing and I wonder what is the relevance...

Comment: @Ray I sometimes use a conda environment, but it's not only the Anaconda interpreter that is gone. All the python interpreters have disappeared from the settings menu.

Comment: Well, I think we have to better isolate the problem before someone else can help you.  The question is whether Python has disappeared from your system or just from `Pycharm`.  If you opened up a terminal, you have something from typing `which python`?  Or `which python3`?  Also, what happens when you activate your conda environment.  Does it have a Python interpreter?  If these interpreters exist, in the screen shot you just posted, can you manually add it back in?

Comment: @Ray python is not gone. I can set up a new python interpreter, so I'm doing that now and reinstalling all my packages manually.

Comment: I see.  I think it's these type of details that you need to provide for someone to help you better.  The first version of your post didn't give this kind of information at all.  For example, it could have been that Pycharm removed it because the underlying Python interpreter was deleted -- so, it helps to say that "it's there still", even if it may seem obvious to you.

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting the `.idea` folder and restarting PyCharm.